# Rails 3 actionmail OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting an OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError when I try to send an email via my contact form.

In my config/application.rb I have addded.

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
     ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
   :address  => "mail.vinderhimlen.dk",
   :port  => 587,
   :user_name  => "asd@vinderhimlen.dk",
   :password  => "x",
   :authentication  => :login
 }
```

My form:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@support], :url => { :action => "create" }, :html => { :method => :post } do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :sender_name, :label => 'Navn' %>
    <%= f.input :email, :label => 'E-mail' %>
    <%= f.input :support_type, :collection => ['Feedback', 'Idé', "Rapporter fejl", 'Business', 'Andet'], :prompt => "Valg type", :label => 'Erinde' %>
    <%= f.label :Besked %>
    <%= f.text_area :content, :label => 'Besked', :style => 'width:500px;', %>
    <%= f.submit "submit", :value => 'Send besked' %>
<% end %>
```

My Supportscontroller:

```
class SupportsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    # id is required to deal with form
    @support = Support.new(:id => 1)
  end

  def create
    @support = Support.new(params[:support])
    if @support.save
      redirect_to('/', :notice => "Support was successfully sent.")
    else
      flash[:alert] = "You must fill all fields."
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

My Support model:

```
class Support
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  validates_presence_of :email, :sender_name, :support_type, :content 
  # to deal with form, you must have an id attribute
  attr_accessor :id, :email, :sender_name, :support_type, :content

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |key, value|
      self.send("#{key}=", value)
    end
    @attributes = attributes
  end

  def read_attribute_for_validation(key)
    @attributes[key]
  end

  def to_key
  end

  def save
    if self.valid?
      Notifier.support_notification(self).deliver
      return true
    end
    return false
  end
end
```

My config/enviroments/devolpment:

```
Konkurranceportalen::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request.  This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the webserver when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
  config.whiny_nils = true

  config.perform_delivery = true

  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_view.debug_rjs             = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Only use best-standards-support built into browsers
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin
end
```

My rails log on when submitting the form:

```
   Started POST "/supports" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-05-31 14:07:07 +0200
      Processing by SupportsController#create as HTML
      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"Ô£ô", "authenticity_token"=>"b4ILe7Xu4moToY8PN1X4wdyejz6
    DQwnZ69FPevAWuSI=", "support"=>{"sender_name"=>"dfsdf", "email"=>"mail@freelance
    rbasen.dk", "support_type"=>"Feedback", "content"=>"dsdsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsadasdasd"}
    , "commit"=>"Send besked"}
      ←[1m←[36mSQL (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT SUM(`tags`.`konkurrancers_count`) AS sum_
    id FROM `tags`←[0m
      ←[1m←[35mSQL (10.0ms)←[0m  describe `kategoris_konkurrancers`
      ←[1m←[36mKonkurrancer Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT `konkurrancers`.* FROM `kon
    kurrancers`←[0m
      ←[1m←[35mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT `konkurrancers`.* FROM `konkurrancers`
      ←[1m←[36mTag Load (1.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags`←[0m
    Rendered notifier/support_notification.html.erb (1.0ms)

    Sent mail to asd@vinderhimlen.dk (277ms)
    Date: Tue, 31 May 2011 14:07:08 +0200

    From: asd@freelancerbasen.dk

    To: asd@vinderhimlen.dk

    Message-ID: <4de4d9ecc67fdsfsdfsdf4ad@Home-Pc.mail>

    Subject: New Feedback

    Mime-Version: 1.0

    Content-Type: text/html;

     charset=UTF-8

    Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable



    =EF=BB=BFhello world!

    dsdsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsadasdasd=

    Completed   in 865ms

    OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (hostname was not match with the server certificate):
      app/models/support.rb:24:in `save'
      app/controllers/supports_controller.rb:9:in `create'

    Rendered C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatc
    h/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.0ms)
      ←[1m←[35mKonkurrancer Load (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT `konkurrancers`.* FROM `konkurr
    ancers` LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0
      ←[1m←[36mSQL (4.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSHOW TABLES←[0m
      ←[1m←[35mSQL (5.0ms)←[0m  SHOW TABLES
    Rendered C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatc
    h/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (252.0ms)
    Rendered C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatc
    h/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (318.0ms)
```

**UPDATE:**

In my config/application.rb:

```
        config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {:enable_starttls_auto => false }
        config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
        config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
             ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
           :address  => "mail.vinderhimlen.dk",
           :port  => 587,
           :user_name  => "asd@vinderhimlen.dk",
           :password  => "x",
           :authentication  => :login,
           :domain => "vinderhimlen.dk",
   :enable_starttls_auto => false
         }
```

Comment: The domain isn't set in your config hash + you should add :enable_starttls_auto => false

Comment: Still not working. I have updated with new code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try

```
:openssl_verify_mode  => 'none'
```

per [Undocumented ActionMailer openssl_verify_mode option](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/892)