# sendmail: OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: hostname was not match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, openssl, sendmail, actionmailer

I have a vps with ubuntu 10.04. i'm tring to install a rails 3 application
If i try to test the sendmail command from terminal it works.

In my application,for the mail, i have inserted in application.rb file:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
    config.action_mailer.sendmail_settings = {
        :location       => '/usr/sbin/sendmail',
        :arguments      => '-i -t'
    }
```

But if i try to send an email with rails i receive this error:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: hostname was not match with the server certificate
    from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/openssl/ssl-internal.rb:123:in `post_connection_check'
```

How can i do?

thanks

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you need

```
:openssl_verify_mode  => 'none'
```

per [Rails 3 actionmail OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187363/rails-3-actionmail-opensslsslsslerror)

Answer (score 1):

just add to your enviroment.rb

```
module OpenSSL
  module SSL
    remove_const :VERIFY_PEER
  end
end
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```