# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError .....certificate verify failed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I just upgraded to Rails `3.2.8` and updated all of my gems. I wanted to test my website so I started at the sign up but when I hit the join button it gives me the error:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError in RegistrationsController#create

SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed

app/models/user.rb:28:in `send_welcome_email'
```

I'm using Devise `2.1.2` with and this is my User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :remember_me
  attr_accessor :accessible # something for devise i think
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, 
  :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, 
  :validatable, :email_regexp =>  /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i

  after_create :send_welcome_email

  private

  def send_welcome_email
    UserMailer.welcome_email(self).deliver
  end
end
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with my email settings in my **development.rb**.

```
require 'tlsmail'
  Net::SMTP.enable_tls(OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)
  ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
  ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
  ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = true
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :address            => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    :port               => 587,
    :tls                => true,
    :domain             => 'app.com',
    :authentication     => :plain,
    :user_name          => 'support@app.com',
    :password           => '******'
  }
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

How can I correct this issue? I just started to get this when I went to `3.2.8`. I'm on Windows 7 if it helps.

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187363/rails-3-actionmail-opensslsslsslerror

Comment: The following post explains the error in detail and suggests several solutions: http://railsapps.github.com/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html

Comment: @jugglinghobo You can make these both an answer if you want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following post by the [RailsApps Project](http://railsapps.github.com/) explains in detail what the problem is and offers multiple solutions for RVM and OSX and Windows.

http://railsapps.github.com/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html

Since you're using Windows, you'll need to [download and install a certificate file](https://gist.github.com/867550) in order to fix your problem. (See the above linked post for a better explanation)

There is also a [github issue](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/319) about the problem.

Comment: Confirmed working solution from the article (`rvm osx-ssl-certs update all`) for installing actionmailer 4.0.0 (for Rails 4.0.0 / ruby-2.0.0-p247) on OSX. Thanks!